# Matplotlib: How to pass a custom FuncScale to set an x or y axis scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The [matplotlib.pyplot.yscale()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) documentation states that one could

> Provide an arbitrary scale with user-supplied function for the axis"

through a [FuncScale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.FuncScale) class. However it is not clear how to specify a `FuncScale` as the documentation doesn't show any other example than this [one](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/scales.html).

How to specify the `functions` and the `axis` argument and why in the example one sets `axis="function"` to custom function scaling?

Comment: What is unclear about the example?  Did you try and run it?

Comment: I'm basically looking for an example detailing the use of `FuncScale`  explaining the use of [axis](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.1/lib/matplotlib/scale.py#L195) and the requirements for the `forward` and `inverse` function.

Comment: For example `forward`  is suggested to `must have an inverse, and for best behavior, be monotic` . However both `forward` and `inverse` just need to be both [callable](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/710fce3df95e22701bd68bf6af2c8adbc9d67a79/lib/matplotlib/scale.py#L147)